# How to insert Google Custom Search into Navigation Menu 'CentralizedMenu'

Tags: jquery, html, menubar

My first post, so forgive me if I haven't done this correctly, and thank you.

I would like to add a  ‘Google Custom Search’ box to ‘Ali Shtarbanov’s menuBar /centralizedMenu’ to the right of the last item 'About' and to the left of the 3 bar icon it creates when the monitor screen is smaller - this menu will collapse / resize on smaller screens to three bars. I’m using html, no php.

When I add the Google code is just creates an empty space, no search box. This is an example of the Google functioning code I’m adding:

```
    <script>
    (function() {
var cx = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxx’;
var gcse = document.createElement('script');
gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
gcse.async = true;
gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Code on his menuBar.html and the output is here:
http://jsbin.com/cotewaxemi/edit?html,output
And pasted in here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>MenuBar</title>
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom CSS: You can use this stylesheet to override any Bootstrap styles and/or apply your own styles -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
        <div class="navbar-header"> <!--This div creates a navigation button visible on smaller screens -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span><!--These tags create the standard 3-lin button logo on top right corner -->
                <span class="icon-bar"></span><!--Put the page less than full-screen to see this behavior -->
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown1<span class="caret"></span></a><!--Requires the JavaScript files linked at the end-->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown2<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">AnotherItem</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Header:</li>
                        <li><a href="#">MoreItems</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MoreItems</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MoreItems</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>  
<!-- JavaScript is required for the dropdown menu -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you again,
Christina
P.S. I wanted to put a link into what I tried to do, but since I am a new member it stated I'm not allowed so many links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working version.

> NOTE : If you can not see the whole menu, click full-page on top right of the panel.

```js
// Make sure in jsFiddle you have selected option onLoad
(function() {
  var cx = '017643444788069204610:4gvhea_mvga'; // Insert your own Custom Search engine ID here
  var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
  gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
      '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
            <div class="navbar-header"> <!--This div creates a navigation button visible on smaller screens -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span><!--These tags create the standard 3-lin button logo on top right corner -->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span><!--Put the page less than full-screen to see this behavior -->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown1<span class="caret"></span></a><!--Requires the JavaScript files linked at the end-->
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown2<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">AnotherItem</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Header:</li>
                            <li><a href="#">MoreItems</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">MoreItems</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">MoreItems</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li id="gsrc"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a></li>
                  <li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav> 
    <!-- JavaScript is required for the dropdown menu -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <!-- jQuery -->

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Google Search</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <gcse:search></gcse:search>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! :D Finally I was able to tick accept

Answer (score 0):

First things first, there is a typo in your code. The problem is with the closing quote. Just change the line and you're good.

```
var cx = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxx’;
```

to

```
var cx = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxx';
```

And second, if you want to do it just as you described, there is a bit of work. You have to put `<gcse:search></gcse:search>` into somewhere on your HTML.

But, you wouldn't want to put it as a list item `<li>` right after about, because when viewing in smaller screens the whole menu becomes collapsed. So what i recommend is to create a new `<div>` with an `ID` and put it inside `<div class="navbar-header">` right after, `</button>`.

The rest is just css. If you have experience with CSS it wouldn't be a problem.

> IMPORTANT NOTICE : Please try first, and where you're stuck, we may gladly help. Just show us how you've come so far. There is a snippet tool when you post a question, where you can paste `JS` , `CSS`, and `HTML` with external library support such as `Jquery` and `Bootstrap`. Don't hesitate to use it,

Comment: Thank you Rüzgar. The typo I pasted here is actually correct on my real file. I'm still working on it and might have found something that works. I will update either way.

Comment: So there shouldn't be any problem, since i tried it on my localhost, and everything woks fine. Maybe the problem is caused by where you put the script.

Comment: Thank you again. I'm trying this out on my existing menu which would be perfect if I can get it to function correctly: <https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/84/how-to-integrate-a-google-custom-search-popup-in-a-bootstrap-navbar> but I will have to continue tomorrow

Comment: Ok. Looking from the example, i tried sth, maybe it can help. Here is the [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/nodupoyupe/edit?html,output)

Comment: Rüzgar you're amazing!!! omgosh I can't wait to try it out tomorrow. Thank you thank you. You're so fast (I hope it is okay if I put thank yous here, as I read rules and no chatting allowed).

Comment: You're welcome. Your thanks are enough. Glad this works for you.

Comment: Rüzgar It is working perfectly, thank you again, so much ...until I change the Google Custom Search code to my own or another, such as Ali's:   var cx = '005180655622273248137:bjgkhj-m09c';  . Then when searching the results are opened in a new tiny result search box on top of the original search box leaving two boxes that need to be closed: http://jsbin.com/jakumahocu/edit?js,output

Comment: Solved the double window: In Google Custom Search 'look and feel' ->  'layout' do not select 'Overly'.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: By the way, I posted a new answer which includes a working version. If you think you are ok with the code, you may call it resolved, so that this may help other people.

Comment: Thank you. I did check the green tick to show resolved - I clicked it again just now. I hope that works.